# laravel web.php having same routes but returning different functions

Tags: php, laravel

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'home', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/page1/{id}', 'PagesController@index')
    Route::get('/page1/{id}','PagesController@getname')
     });
```

and my controller is like so

```
return view('pages.page1')->with(['test'=> $output]);
```

but when i access my page 1 it says undefined variable page 1
so basically there are two functions in `PagesController` and both of them are returning to a details page

Comment: Can you show the whole controller? There's no variable page 1 in what you showed. Also, it's not possible to point 2 same URLs to different functions.

Comment: why do you use same route ? I think if you use multiple  route in same value i'll only accept last one

Answer (score 0):

**Two identical URLs** cannot point to different functions unless they have different ***http requests***.  eg: GET, POST, PUT,etc.

In your case the `PagesController@index` will be triggered every time the url is accessed since it lies above the `PagesController@getname`.